# Calculating hourly volatility and peak-to-average ratio in R

Tags: r, aggregation

I have network traffic data in the following for for each hour of a ten day period as follows in a R dataset.

```
   Day   Hour         Volume          Category
    0    00            100            P2P
    0    00            50             email
    0    00            200            gaming
    0    00            200            video
    0    00            150            web
    0    00            120            P2P
    0    00            180            web
    0    00            80             email
    ....
    0    01            150            P2P
    0    01            200            P2P
    0    01             50            Web
    ...
    ...
    10   23            100            web
    10   23            200            email
    10   23            300            gaming
    10   23            300            gaming
```

As seen there are repetitions of Category within a single hour also. I need to calculate the volatility and the peak hour to average hour ratios of these different application categories.

**Volatility**: Standard deviation of hourly volumes divided by hourly average.

**Peak hour to avg. hour ratio**: Ratio of volume of the maximum hour to the volume of the average hour for that application.

So how do I aggregate and calculate these two statistics for each category? I am new to R and don't have much knowledge of how to aggregate and get the averages as mentioned.

So, the final result would look something like this

```
Category    Volatility      Peak to Avg. Ratio
Web            0.55            1.5
P2P            0.30            2.1
email          0.6             1.7
gaming         0.4             2.9
```

Comment: Does the identical hour on different days count as the same hour or not? If an hour has no use of particular application, do you want that to be counted as 0 for the standard deviation and average calculation?  When you say "Ratio of volume of the maximum hour to the vol. of the average hour", I presume *vol.* means *volume* rather than *volatility*.

Comment: @Henry yes, what it should do is aggregate all the hours of all the days by adding the volumes per category so all the corresponding hourly volumes and added into one representing all the days in one single 24 hour period. then perform the calculations for each Catgory giving me the result in the form shown.

Comment: @Henry and yes vol. is for volume and if the category is not present in any hour it is 0 (though there are no such cases in the actual data :).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [plyr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html), which has [great documentation](http://had.co.nz/plyr/). While you could solve your problem with `aggregate()` function, I'd argue that learning the plyr family of functions will be worth it in the end.

For your specific problem, this would obtain what you want:

```
stats = ddply(
    .data = my_data
    , .variables = .( Hour , Category)
    , .fun = function(x){
        to_return = data.frame(
            volatility = sd(x$Volume)/mean(x$Volume)
            , pa_ratio = max(x$Volume)/mean(x$Volume)
        )
        return( to_return )
    }
)
```

Comment: Now that I re-read your post, I'm unsure what you were asking. The code I provided computes a volatility and Peak hour to avg. hour ratio score for each hour and each category, collapsing across days (eg. the volatility for email in hour 0 is computed using the hour 0 data for email from all days).

Comment: well this looks like a good way but what it means is first aggregate the entire 10 day period into one single 24 hour period (for each category by summing the volumes). And then for each category on this aggregated 24 hour period measure the volatility and the Peak to Avg ratio for each "Category"

Comment: I've added a sample output in the question :).